# jQuery UI datepicker - closes with a custom selectmenu

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drop-down-menu, datepicker

I have jQuery UI installed and am currently having an issue with the datepicker widget. I have the calendar displayed when you click on the icon and it is generated. The calendar has a select menu for Month and Year. I am using the jQuery UI custom select menu.

When I go to make a selection for the selectmenus, the option selected closes/discards the entire datepicker.

My assumption is that there is an event being triggered to close the datepicker when you click outside of the main widget. The custom selectmenu is not the standard 'select' menu with 'options', but rather a bunch of 'spans'. The code is simply acknowledging the click on the custom selectmenu options as a field outside of the original widget.

Any suggestions or assistance to prevent this trigger or help me locate where this event is firing from, feel free to help me out. Thanks

Comment: It will help a lot if you create a fiddle that reproduces the problem.

Comment: That would help...Ill create one now

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/hmk0t9ep/